# регулярные выражения python, выражения в скобках

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Все привет, не могу разобраться с регулярками, помогите пожалуйста. Написал такую: `\[[\s\S]+\|[\s\S]+\]` и пример текста

> [test|test2]some text [test3|test4] some text2

Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно забрать только те выражения которые в квадратных скобках, а моя регулярка забирает и то что в скобках и то что между ними, т.е в примере он заберет `[test|test2]some text [test3|test4]` а нужно только `[test|test2]` и  `[test3|test4]`

Comment: расставьте экраны на соответствующие символы, к примеру без экранирования символ пайпа `|` это логическое или.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[[\s\S]*?\]
```

`?` - квантифайер "ленивого" поиска. Ищет, до тех пор, пока условие не станет удовлетворено.

Простыми словами - с `?` ищется самая короткая подходящая подстрока, без `?` — самая длинная.